# Proper linking of actionSherlock in an Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

I'm a newbie when it comes to Android Programming. And right now, I'm practicing basic elements with android. I was successful in creating buttons that link to other activities and creating swipey tabs in a separate manner.

Now, the trouble is that when I try to merge those 2, I'm having difficulties doing so.

There are no warnings or errors in the coding as per eclipse, but when I click the button where it should show the activity with swipeytabs, the app shuts down.

Here's the logCat content:

06-03 17:48:57.678: I/ActionBarSherlock(907): Registering ActionBarSherlockCompat with qualifier @com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock$Implementation(api=7, dpi=-1)
06-03 17:48:57.708: I/ActionBarSherlock(907): Registering ActionBarSherlockNative with qualifier @com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock$Implementation(api=14, dpi=-1)
06-03 17:48:57.748: I/ActionBarSherlock(907): Using implementation: ActionBarSherlockNative
06-03 17:48:57.748: D/ActionBarSherlock(907): [] activity: com.example.pixelapp3.page3@412409f8, flags: 1
06-03 17:48:57.758: D/ActionBarSherlock(907): [setContentView] view: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager@41243fe0
06-03 17:48:57.779: D/ActionBarSherlock(907): [setContentView] view: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager@41243fe0, params: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams@41252b70
06-03 17:48:57.858: D/dalvikvm(907): GC_CONCURRENT freed 178K, 3% free 8291K/8519K, paused 115ms+13ms, total 305ms
06-03 17:48:57.858: D/dalvikvm(907): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 54ms
06-03 17:48:57.908: D/ActionBarSherlock(907): [getActionBar]
06-03 17:48:57.928: D/ActionBarSherlock(907): [getActionBar]
06-03 17:48:57.948: V/21st Polling:(907): clicked
06-03 17:48:58.098: D/AndroidRuntime(907): Shutting down VM
06-03 17:48:58.098: W/dalvikvm(907): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.pixelapp3.page3a cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.example.pixelapp3.TabsAdapter.getItem(TabsAdapter.java:97)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:829)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:979)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-03 17:48:58.188: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. i don't know if I also imported actiobarSherlock properly. will do a recheck

Comment: Nobody is going to download your source code to look at what may potentially be wrong. If the app crashes you get an exception in the `Logcat`. Posting that exception along with the related code will get you much more help with the problems.

Comment: you should post a minimalistic code-sample instead of zip files. Most people ( me included ) are to lazy/paranoia downloading stuff

Comment: Please delete the two comments above and edit your question and add the exception there. In the TabsAdapter it seems you're trying to cast something(the page3a class) as a fragment which isn't a fragment.

Comment: redid page3a to 3d

something's wrong, but there are not errors or warnings appearing, it only shows on the logCat